# IE8 Filter gradient on body disables page scroll

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am using the IE filter to make the background have a gradient, but only in IE8 does it have an issue. These lines make the background gradient correctly but the page will no longer scroll:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat fixed;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ) no-repeat fixed; /* IE6-8 */
```

I have also tried setting the height to 100%.
What is wrong?

http://asthmaready.org/training-programs/

Comment: Such is life when using IE's horrible `filter` property. I haven't heard of this bug before, but there are plenty of others to watch out for. Oh, and why are you using a base64 image for the gradient in other browsers? Why not use CSS `linear-gradient`?

Comment: I am also using linear-gradient, but its not supported by IE8, I found exactly my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8636924/744228

Answer (score 1):

try to attach filter-gradient to `div#page`

**UPDATE**:

```
body.cbgc {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%, rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%) no-repeat fixed;
    ....
}
```

somehow blocks subsequent `#page` style declaration, so when you apply a filter to it, it is ignored. Try to remove and apply filter to `#page` it to see if this helps.

Another point is that gradient on `#page` will not end on the screen edge (as in other browsers) instead it will proceed to the scrolled area. If this is relevant to you, you can add additional div, a sibling with `#page`, and apply to it that filter and position fixed. So everything will look the same as in non-IE browsers

Comment: strange, I tried this in IE8 dev-toolbar and all worked fine. Though, I've removed position:relative to add filter, may be this is the cause

Comment: It makes it either white (only filter) or blue (filter+bg)

Comment: you are using rgba color. I'm not sure that this filter supports also opacity. It seems that you must to pick up some other color to IE8 background, more "whiter"

Comment: So I said screw it and used `background: url(/static/bg.png) fixed 100%;`

Comment: Something very strange. The main problem, I can't find answer to, is the ignoring `#page` selector in your embeded css. I'll return to this tomorrow if nobody else will not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem! As Caligula answered, don't apply the filter to the body, the -moz, -webkit, ... however will work fine. Apply the `filter:progid` to the first div inside your body (if needed add a `div.container {height:100% width:100%}`)