# Backround image with linear gradient not showing up in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using the following css for an element. It only breaks with Internet Explorer 8.

```
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png);
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), linear-gradient(bottom, #383838 0%, #666666 100%);
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #383838 0%, #666666 100%);
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #383838 0%, #666666 100%);
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #383838 0%, #666666 100%);
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #0c93C0, #FFF);
/*IE7-*/ background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#383838', endColorStr='#666666', GradientType=0);
/*IE8+*/ background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#383838', endColorStr='#666666', GradientType=0)"; 
background-image: url(../images/icon-save.png), -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0, #383838),
color-stop(1, #666666)
);
```

I would expect that either -ms-filter or -ms-linear-gradient would work but this is not the case. 
I went through topics in stackoverflow but I did not find any containing an image.

Comment: As far as I remember from my webdeveloper days where I had to support these versions, `filter` and `-ms-filter` collide. Try omitting the ms-filter declaration and see what happens.

Comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` is not really necessary; this prefix was only used for early pre-release versions of IE10. The full release of IE10 does not require the prefix, and earlier versions of IE do not support standard CSS gradients at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately non of the above worked. What I ended up doing was adding the following to an IE8-only css file.

```
background: url(../../../../modules/contrib/panels/panels_ipe/images/icon-close.png) no-repeat #666666;
```

I consider this a much worst approach than both 2 suggested above, but since I coundn't make them work I will mark this as an answer. I am open to suggestions if someone considers the answer misleading :)

Comment: +1 because this is, of course, a perfectly valid solution. You don't need this in an IE8-specific CSS file, because if you specify it above the other `background` declarations, other browsers will see it but override with the gradient background that comes after it, so it can be in the same file without any issues. But did you try CSS3Pie I suggested? I'm surprised it didn't work for you. (you may need to read the documentation for any specific advice on setting it up, but it ought to support what you're trying to do)

Comment: I tried it. I also asked a question and went through the questions. However it seems like a very nice tool which I will use in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing a jsFiddle or having a link to your site I'm assuming somewhat here, but you're attempting multiple background images yes? An image + a background gradient?

IE8 doesn't support multiple background images as it's a CSS3 specification. However, this might do the trick:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#383838", endColorstr="#666666",GradientType=0 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/icon-save.png");
```

See this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636924/ie-8-gradient-backgroundimage).

Comment: should the filter be used in background or background image?

Comment: I believe background-image.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're basically trying to do stuff that IE8 doesn't support. Even with the `filter` gradients (which are very buggy at the best of times), old-IE can't handle multiple backgrounds like this. It's just too new as a CSS feature to expect browsers as old as IE8 to support it.

You may be able to hack with the `filter` style to make it work, but it's going to be painful. I'd avoid it if I were you.

Fortunately, there is another option: [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is a little JS library that plugs into your stylesheets and adds various features to IE's CSS support, including CSS gradients and multiple background images.

This means you can throw away all that nasty proprietary `filter` code, and replace it with standard CSS code even for old IE versions.

Sure, it adds an extra bit of script code to your site, but it will only ever be loaded by old IE versions, so it won't affect other users, and it will make your code much easier to work with.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

use filter

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#383838", endColorstr="#666666",GradientType=0 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="../images/icon-save.png");
```

Comment: How did you get this one to work? I tried it and the image never load.

Comment: The same for me, but ```DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader``` without gradient works fine. You can add gradient in parent element.